# Calendar input ignoring next input line

Tags: java, calendar

Couldn't get my head around this.

The below code compiles and runs well, except for one problem - right after the `inputReg` lines for the date of birth (day, month, year part), the next part of the code will be skipped for some reason.

In this code's case, the program ignores the `tel = inputReg.nextLine();` right after the creation of Calendar.

I've fooled around with the placement of the Date of Birth part, and found out that the next `inputReg.nextLine()` part will always be skipped over if it is placed after the Date of Birth part.

Running this section of the code:

```
  Scanner inputReg = new Scanner(System.in);

  //initialization of attributes
  String IC = "";
  String name = "";
  String tel = "";

  int day = 0;
  int month = 0;
  int year = 0;
  //for date

  System.out.print("Enter IC number: ");
  IC = inputReg.nextLine();

  Calendar dob = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);

  System.out.print("Enter name: ");
  name = inputReg.nextLine();

  System.out.println("Enter Date of Birth (DD/MM/YYYY ): ");
  day = inputReg.nextInt();
  month = inputReg.nextInt();
  year = inputReg.nextInt();

  System.out.print("Enter telephone number: ");
  tel = inputReg.nextLine();

  Customer c = new Customer(IC, name, dob, tel);
  customerList.add(c);

  System.out.println("Customer " + c.getName() + " registered successfuly.");
  System.out.println(tel);
```

Gives me this output:

```
Enter IC number: XX11
Enter name: Bob
Enter Date of Birth (DD/MM/YYYY ): 
10
10
2000
Enter telephone number: Customer Bob registered successfuly.

//ends
```

I know that it is possible for me to simply place the Date of Birth area at the very bottom, but I'm not satisfied by doing that.

**My question is: What's causing the inputReg.nextLine() part to always get skipped?**

By the way, I've only encountered this problem when having the code interact with Calendar, so maybe there's something new that I'm not getting.

Comment: may be cause you are using nextInt() before nextLine() and need to do something in between to make sure that it doesn't ignore that

Comment: Ah, thanks. I've realized that I needed to add something that'd 'consume' the nextInt() part (not sure how to say this, though). So that's why nextLIne() comes in handy.

Thank you, the question is now answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by doing this (if that's what you wanted?)

```
    package com.stackoverflow.solutionmaker;

    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class StackOverflowSolutionsRunner {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

             Scanner inputReg = new Scanner(System.in);

              //initialization of attributes
              String IC = "";
              String name = "";
              String tel = "";

              int day = 0;
              int month = 0;
              int year = 0;
              //for date

              System.out.print("Enter IC number: ");
              IC = inputReg.nextLine();

              Calendar dob = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);

              System.out.print("Enter name: ");
              name = inputReg.nextLine();

              System.out.println("Enter Date of Birth (DD/MM/YYYY ): ");
              day = inputReg.nextInt();
              month = inputReg.nextInt();
              year = inputReg.nextInt();
              inputReg.nextLine(); // I added this line to fake an input

              System.out.print("Enter telephone number: ");
              tel = inputReg.nextLine();

              //Customer c = new Customer(IC, name, dob, tel);
              //customerList.add(c);

              //System.out.println("Customer " + c.getName() + " registered successfuly.");
              System.out.println(tel);      

} }
```

BTW - commented out code that I couldn't see from you?

I believe this sentence from nextLine() method's excerpt from Oracle docs is a clue? : `Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.`

Also, nextInt() possibly doesn't reset the input to the begenning of the line? ( just assuming).

Comment: Yes, that is right. I've actually stumbled onto it after you wrote your comment, though your actual answer helped.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is your `nextInt` method not reads new line character that you enter value for `year = inputReg.nextInt()`. you could resolve it in two ways.

**Solution 1**

add a `nextLine` method to captured `'\n'`

```
year = inputReg.nextInt();
inputReg.nextLine();
```

**Solution 2**

read input using only `nextLine()`

```
year = Integer.parseInt(inputReg.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

Stumped upon it after a helpful hint. Didn't 'consume' the line after nextInt() and before using nextLine(), thus nextLine() got ignored.